# Удаленный доступ в папку с документами для бухгалтера

Tags: windows

В офисе локальная сеть, в некоторых почти никому не доступных папках лежат сметы и договора. Как можно организовать удаленный доступ бухгалтеру именно в эту папку и подпапки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это зависит от многих причин. Например от того как организован доступ извне к вашим компьютерам. Обычно, этим занимаются системные администраторы. Уточните как организовани сеть, как организован доступ в интернет и т.п. Для организации доступа к секретной информации нужно будет не забыть о безопасности и т.п., задача, скорее, не для пользователя...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал доступ по *ssh* - защищенный канал для передачи данных.

Answer (score 0):

Эти папки находятся на фаилсервере? У него есть выход в инет? Как подключен интернет расскажи. Если инет настроен через роутер то сделай проброс портов для RDP на этот сервер, на сервере сделай учетку бухгалтера которая имелобы доступ к этим папкам и все))

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить нафига RDP?!   В варианте подобного решения (с пробросом портов) я бы воспользовался SFTP. И проблем меньше, и защищенный, и порты можно любые указать. FileZilla (для Винды, с клиентском машины) прекрасно отработает этот вариант. На файл-сервер достаточно поставить freeSSHd - он имеет встроенный SFTP.